# CAS OAuth with Google

Tags: oauth, google-oauth, cas

I wanna use CAS 3.5.2 with Google Oauth - so I did configuration exactly like here:
https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASUM/Configuration+for+the+OAuth+client+support+in+CAS+server+version+%3E%3D+3.5.1

I also included:
cas-server-support-oauth-3.5.2.jar
scribe-up-1.2.0.jar

But I still receive following error and do not know what I am doing wrong:

```
2013-11-29 12:42:45,519 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] - <Context     initialization failed>
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name     'google' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-    configuration/applicationContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is     java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/scribe/model/OAuthRequest
    at     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:997)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:943)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:385)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:284)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
at org.jasig.cas.web.init.SafeContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized_aroundBody0(SafeContextLoaderListener.java:75)
at org.jasig.cas.web.init.SafeContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized_aroundBody1$advice(SafeContextLoaderListener.java:57)
at org.jasig.cas.web.init.SafeContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(SafeContextLoaderListener.java:1)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:983)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1660)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/scribe/model/OAuthRequest
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2493)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2803)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2053)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:67)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:990)
... 29 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.scribe.model.OAuthRequest
    at     org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1702)
    at     org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
    ... 35 more
```

in my applicationContext.xml I added:

```
<bean id="google" class="org.scribe.up.provider.impl.GoogleProvider">
 <property name="key" value="myvalue" />
 <property name="secret" value="mysecret" />
</bean>

<bean id="oauthConfig" class="org.jasig.cas.support.oauth.OAuthConfiguration">
  <property name="loginUrl" value="https://my.login.com/login" />
  <property name="providers">
    <list>
      <ref bean="google" />
    </list>
  </property>
 </bean>
```

what am I missing?????

thank you!!

Comment: same error with scribe-up-1.3.1.jar

Answer (score 0):

I'm the creator of the *scribe-up* and *cas-server-support-oauth* libraries. The documentation is accurate. I have a demo to test the OAuth support : `https://github.com/leleuj/cas-oauth-demo-3.5.x`.

That said, the error you have : `ClassNotFoundException: org.scribe.model.OAuthRequest` means that the *Scribe* library (used by *scribe-up*) is missing (version 1.3.2 is required). This should not happen as it's a dependency : `http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/scribe/scribe-up/1.2.0/scribe-up-1.2.0.pom`.

Comment: My next problem with Google is following ######2013-12-02 09:27:04,300 ERROR [org.scribe.up.provider.BaseOAuth10Provider] - <No credential found>
2013-12-02 09:27:04,302 ERROR [org.jasig.cas.authentication.AuthenticationManagerImpl] - <org.jasig.cas.support.oauth.authentication.handler.support.OAuthAuthenticationHandler threw error authenticating org.jasig.cas.support.oauth.authentication.principal.OAuthCredentials@2c04fa9>####### Facebook is working. Can you please help once again?!

Comment: If I understand it correctly we have to use following: Google2Provider (use scribe-up 1.3.1 dependency instead of scribe-up 1.2.0 if you use CAS server 3.5.2) -> but I am using scribe-up 1.3.1!!!!! So why is there an error with BaseOAuth10Provider???? And which credentials???

Comment: OAuthKey is enabled within GoogleAdmin. And I used Key and Secret within applicationContext.xml. hmmmmmmm

Comment: Right, you need to use the Google2Provider and scribe-up 1.3.1. "No credential found" means that after a successful authentication on Google, you have been redirected to your CAS server without the OAuth code. What is the redirection url to your CAS server after Google's login ?

Comment: Hi and thank you very much for your help!!!!! I added following to applicationContext.xml:

Comment: `code`<bean id="google" class="org.scribe.up.provider.impl.GoogleProvider">
 <property name="key" value="mykey" />
 <property name="secret" value="mysecret" />
</bean>


<bean id="oauthConfig" class="org.jasig.cas.support.oauth.OAuthConfiguration">
  <property name="loginUrl" value="https://my.cas.com/login" />
  <property name="providers">
    <list>
      <ref bean="google" />
    </list>
  </property>
 </bean>

Comment: When using org.scribe.up.provider.impl.Google2Provider instead of GoogleProvider I get following errer when accessing https/my.cas.com/login in the browser: There was an error trying to complete your request. Please notify your support desk or try again.

Comment: This error is not very relevant : don't you have any stack trace somewhere ? I think I remember there is a bug on this provider : would you mind explicitely setting the scope (else I think you might get a NullPointerException) ?

Comment: Hm, no, there is no other log. only these infos are available in cas.log:

Comment: 2013-12-04 11:48:10,494 INFO [org.jasig.cas.services.DefaultServicesManagerImpl] - Loaded 1 services.
2013-12-04 11:48:11,653 INFO [org.jasig.cas.util.AutowiringSchedulerFactoryBean] - Starting Quartz Scheduler now
2013-12-04 11:48:21,990 INFO [org.jasig.cas.web.flow.InitialFlowSetupAction] - Setting path for cookies to: /
2013-12-04 11:48:21,990 INFO [org.jasig.cas.web.flow.InitialFlowSetupAction] - Setting path for cookies to: /

Comment: 2013-12-04 11:48:30,103 INFO [org.jasig.cas.ticket.registry.support.DefaultTicketRegistryCleaner] - Beginning ticket cleanup.
2013-12-04 11:48:30,104 INFO [org.jasig.cas.ticket.registry.support.DefaultTicketRegistryCleaner] - 0 tickets found to be removed.
2013-12-04 11:48:30,104 INFO [org.jasig.cas.ticket.registry.support.DefaultTicketRegistryCleaner] - Finished ticket cleanup.

Comment: ahh, you are writing about this bug:

Comment: I will give it a try - but set the scope to which value?

Comment: By the way - do you recommend Using CAS 4.0 instead final 3.5.2 when authenticating against google?!

Comment: ah, now I also found your answer here. lets try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17494412/cas-oauth-authentication-using-google-oauth-2-0-and-using-yahoo-oauth-1-0

Comment: hmmm, I don't get it working. I am not able to set the scope explicitely within applicationContext.xml....

Comment: CAS 4.0 will be released in the beginning of next year so it really depends on the timeline of your project, but yes, I would recommend to target CAS 4.0 instead of 3.5.2 which is based on pac4j I'm currently developing and not on scribe-up (which is deprecated).

Comment: The scope to set depends on what you want to retrieve from Google (https://github.com/leleuj/pac4j/blob/1.3.x/src/main/java/org/scribe/up/provider/impl/Google2Provider.java#L46) : email and/or profile.